# Designing a database for a workout tracker

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database for a workout tracker app. Each user should be able to track multiple workouts (routines). A workout can have multiple exercises an exercise can be used in many workouts. Each exercise will have a specific track type (weight and reps, distance and time, only reps).

My tables so far:

```
| User |       |
|------|-------|
| id   | name  |
| 1    | Ilka  |
| 2    | James |

| Exercise |                     |               |
|----------|---------------------|---------------|
| id       | name                | track_type_id |
| 1        | Barbell Bench Press | 1             |
| 2        | Squats              | 1             |
| 3        | Deadlifts           | 1             |
| 4        | Rowing Machine      | 3             |

| Workout |         |                 |
|---------|---------|-----------------|
| id      | user_id | name            |
| 1       | 1       | Chest & Triceps |
| 2       | 1       | Legs            |

| Workout_Exerice (Junction table)   |            |
|-----------------|------------------|------------|
| id              | exersice_id      | workout_id |
| 1               | 1                | 1          |
| 2               | 2                | 1          |
| 3               | 4                | 1          |

| Workout_Sets |                     |      |        |
|--------------|---------------------|------|--------|
| id           | workout_exersice_id | reps | weight |
| 1            | 1                   | 12   | 120    |
| 2            | 1                   | 10   | 120    |
| 3            | 1                   | 8    | 120    |
| 4            | 2                   | 10   | 220    |
| 5            | 3                   | null | null   |

| TrackType |                 |
|-----------|-----------------|
| id        | name            |
| 1         | Weight and Reps |
| 2         | Reps Only       |
| 3         | Distance Time   |
```

My issue is how to incorporate the `TrackType` table for each workout set, my first option was to create columns in the `Workout_Sets` table for each tracking type (weight and reps, distance and time, only reps) but that means for many rows I will have many nulls. Another option I thought was to use an EAV type table but I'm not sure. Also do you think my design is efficient (Over-normalization)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the most efficient way is to have nulls in your table. The alternative would require you to split many of the category's into separate tables. Also a recommendation is that you start factoring a User ID table into your database